# как передать многомерный вектор в функцию?

Tags: c++, vector

имеется двумерный вектор вида

```
vector <vector<int>> vi (n, vector<int>(m, 0));
```

как его передать в функцию, например, по ссылке?

Comment: если я верно понел ваши намерения, то  вместе с std::slice(0, n, m)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если у вас функция объявлена как

```
void func(vector<vector<int>>&v);
```

или

```
void func(const vector<vector<int>>&v);
```

то передаем

```
vector <vector<int>> vi (n, vector<int>(m, 0));
```

просто как

```
func(vi);
```

Или вы хотите спросить что-то иное?

Comment: удивлен, что это неизвестно автору вопроса:::